# What does this Smart contract mean?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, tokens, web3-providers

can I get an explanation about this section of the smart contract
especially the supply function. and what does

```
 totalSupply = _supply * 10**_decimals;
```

means?
I will like to created a mintable token with maximum supply capped

```
contract CoinToken is PausableToken {
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint public decimals;
uint public supply_cap;
event Mint(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);


constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint256 _decimals, uint256 _supply, address tokenOwner) public {
    name = _name;
    symbol = _symbol;
    decimals = _decimals;
    totalSupply = _supply * 10**_decimals;
    balances[tokenOwner] = totalSupply;
    owner = tokenOwner;
    
    emit Transfer(address(0), tokenOwner, totalSupply);
}

function burn(uint256 _value) public {
    _burn(msg.sender, _value);
}

function _burn(address _who, uint256 _value) internal {
    require(_value <= balances[_who]);
    balances[_who] = balances[_who].sub(_value);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
    emit Burn(_who, _value);
    emit Transfer(_who, address(0), _value);
}

function mint(address account, uint256 amount) onlyOwner public {

    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(amount);
    balances[account] = balances[account].add(amount);
    emit Mint(address(0), account, amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `totalSupply` saves the supply taking the decimals into account. The `**` operator means power to the following number, is like saying 10^_decimals.

Lets say you have a `_supply = 1` with `_decimals = 0`, the total supply would be `1 * 10^0` = `1*1` = `1`.

That would mean that if you mint 1 means 1 tokens.

There is no getting lost with that, but let's say we support 2 decimals:

```
_supply = 1;
_decimals = 2;
totalSupply = 1*(10^2);
totalSupply = 100;
```

That would mean that if you mint 50 means 0.5 tokens. Or if you mint 100 its 1 token.

Comment: Thanks Julissa, that means, if I created a token with decimal as 2, 
i can have 0.01 as the minimum right?